# Automatically publish errors from errorChannel to the specific destination

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

This [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling) says, that it is possible to automatically send error messages from global *errorChannel* to specific destination, the only thing needed is to set the following property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.error.destination
```

I am really confused with this part. Just adding property doesn't work (I use RabbitMQ, Exchange and Queue are configured). So I can see error handled by @ServiceActivator in my application, but it is not sent to "myErrors" exchange in RabbitMQ. Looks like this property does not define outbound binding for *errorChannel*.

If I create output "error" channel explicitly in my application,

```
/**
 * Error channel name.
 */
String ERROR_ONE = "error";

@Output(MySink.ERROR_ONE)
MessageChannel errorOne();
```

and explicitly send error message to it from my global handler, for example by declaring outputChannel:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "error")
public ErrorMessage errorGlobal(ErrorMessage message) {
    System.out.println("Handling ERROR GLOBAL SA: " + message);
    return message;
}
```

it will work. But this can be done to binding-specific handlers also, so there is nothig *errorChannel*-specific here.

**The question:** Do I miss something? Can publish be done without defining outbound channels explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation about `...binding.errors...` is obsolete and needs to be fixed.

You should use `auto-bind-dlq` and `republish-to-dlq` instead and the framwork will publish the failed message to the dlq, with additional headers with information about the failure.